# XTB API Discrepancies in candles vs tick prices

Tags: api, algorithmic-trading

I'm playing with the [XTB API](http://developers.xstore.pro/documentation/current). The two streams from getCandles and getTickPrices don't return the same value ranges. The ask and bid values are approx. €0.30 higher and lower, respectively, for Bitcoin. That makes it difficult for me to build a dynamic chart from them. Is there a reason for these differences?

Edit/Addition: The values from getCandles correspond to the charts on their web app "XStation 5". The tick prices are the ones that are off by a few cents.

final edit: Nevermind. I sent "2" as value for "maxLevel" in the request. Set it to 0 and the numbers match now. I don't mind anyone telling me what that maxLevel parameter means. It's probably off topic now though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the two are supposed to do different things:

- ticks are supposed to provide information on order book (number and volume of bids and asks), so there are multiple prices possible at the same time, just different parties are biding/asking different prices with different volumes,
- candles are supposed to provide information on transactions (volume of trades and average price of transactions),

I think if you select in XTB xstation client "show market depth" option you exactly see what getTicks provides, while prices drawn on the graph are the getCandles results.